# In python, how to match a string with QRegExp that may start with # character?

Tags: python, regex, pyqt

I'm trying to highlight a certain word that appears within a string, but this word can change and can feature alpha numeric characters, as well as things like '#', '$', '-', and '_'.

Right now I have this:

```
pattern = "\\b" + QRegExp.escape(word) + "\\b"
regex = QRegExp(pattern)
index = regex.indexIn(self.edit_box.toPlainText(), pos)
```

And then I highlight based on the starting index and the length of the selected word by moving a cursor through with a certain background color.

The problem exists in the following case:

```
sentence = "#ff0000 hey this is a test #ff0000"
word = "#ff0000"
pattern = "\\b" + QRegExp.escape(word) + "\\b"
regex = QRegExp(pattern)
pos = 0
index = regex.indexIn(sentence, pos)
while (index != -1):
     print 'this is entered'
print 'done!'

output: done!
```

It seems that a leading '#' may just be treating the regex pattern as just a comment, even with QRegExp.escape().

Comment: Word boundaries are the boundaries between a word character (letters, numbers, underscore) and either non-word-characters (everything else) or the start/end of the string. Space and # are both non-word-characters. You can build a custom boundary using lookarounds, e.g `(?<!\w)#ff0000(?!\w)`.

Comment: I do not think [QRegExp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) supports lookbehind. I guess `pattern = "(?:^|\\W)(" + QRegExp.escape(word) + ")(?!\\w)"` will do here, just the index of Group 1 should be taken, `regex.pos(1)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems so, well the alternative using alternation and rearranging the index is already in your answer.

Comment: Word boundary is equivalent to `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`, `\b#` doesn't satisfy either of them

Answer (score 2):

You required a word char to appear before `#` when used `\b#ff000\b` pattern. In general, [`\b` word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) are context dependent, thus, whenever your search words are dynamic and may contain special chars, you need to consider using alternatives.

If you just want to prevent any word char to appear before and after the search word, use

```
pattern = "(?:^|\\W)(" + QRegExp.escape(word) + ")(?!\\w)"
```

If you want to only match the search word in between whitespaces and start/end of string, use

```
pattern = "(?:^|\\s)(" + QRegExp.escape(word) + ")(?!\\S)"
```

To get the right index, after checking if there is a match with `rx.indexIn`, you may get the necessary index of the Group 1 match using `regex.pos(1)`.

Comment: What is regex in this case? For when you call regex.pos{1}